# QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method when using inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have got a super class `Common`, which inherits from `QObject`. Then I have got a class `Item`, which inherits from `Common`.

**Common.h**

```
class Common : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // some methods
};
```

**Item.h**

```
class Item : public Common {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // some methods
    void test(QString value);
};
```

**Item.cpp**

```
void Item::test(QString value) {
    qDebug() << value;
}
```

I want to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to dynamically call a function.
So I implemented a test function in the `Item` class, which takes exactly one string.

```
Item* item = new Item();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(item, "test", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QString, "1234"));
```

This does not work. I get the following error: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method Common::test(QString)`, which is perfectly okay and fine, because the `Common` class has no `test` function.

How can I tell `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, that it should call the method from the `Item` class?

Comment: Does `class Item` have `Q_OBJECT` macro? It's required in order to make slots known to the meta-object system. Adding slots is still possible, but they will only be normal functions then. Also, the function needs to be a slot (or a `Q_INVOKABLE` method) in the first place.

Comment: No it hasn't. I added it, but still get the error. Should I edit my question and put the necessary source code in it or do you have another hint?

Comment: When you add the macro, re-run qmake. It needs to scan your files for the macro in order to know that it needs to run `moc` on it. Another pitfall of Qt... ;)

Comment: If that didn't help, yes, some more code could help.

Comment: I edited my question and inserted the necessary code.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod` can only invoke methods known to the Qt meta object system. These are slots and "invokable" functions, the latter being functions with the keyword `Q_INVOKABLE` before them.

So either write:

```
class Item : public Common {
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    // ^^^^^
    void test(QString value);
};
```

or:

```
class Item : public Common {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void test(QString value);
    //^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: `Q_INVOKABLE void test(QString value);` did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Niklas Yes, I added it in an edit :) I prefer `Q_INVOKABLE` over slots if the function is never used in a signal-slot connection. But for a lot of functions, just saying `public slots:` is less typing :)

Comment: What if i use `invokeMethod()` on a method of an instance of Qt class, which i can't change to be slot? In my case it looks like this: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(scene, "addItem", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QGraphicsItem*, dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem*>(currentPixmap)));` Is there a way?