# Q_INVOKABLE on all getters and setters functions inside QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I have some fields in my class. I want to have `Q_PROPERTY` on all these fields and also have getters and setters.

Example for the private field `float pwm7Min`, I can get my getters and setters and also property using this code.

```
Q_PROPERTY(float pwm7Min READ getPwm7Min WRITE setPwm7Min NOTIFY pwm7MinChanged)
```

This is generated by automatic in QT.

[image]

**Question:**

But I want to `Q_INVOKABLE` all the setters and getters. Is there a way to do that in QT by using QT Designer, or do I have to manually implement them by my self?

That's because I have got this error and the solution is `Q_INVOKABLE`. But my `.cpp` file is over 1000 lines of code and only contains getters and setters.

```
 QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method IOcalibration::setInputCapture0Max(float)
```

It have origins from this problem: [QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method when using inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642370/qmetaobjectinvokemethod-no-such-method-when-using-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a `Q_PROPERTY` you can access the object through the property name in `QML`, you don't need to declare any setter or getter as `Q_INVOKABLE`, because the property it's already registered in the meta object system.

if you have

```
Q_PROPERTY(float pwm7Min READ getPwm7Min WRITE setPwm7Min NOTIFY pwm7MinChanged)
```

then just access in qml via

```
pwm7Min = 0.5
```

use setter/getter there is just wrong, that's why Qt Creator does not provide that option.

Comment: To make this work don't forget to add your class to qml context.

```QQmlEngine engine;

MyClass myClass;

QQmlContext *context = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());

context->setContextProperty("myClass", &myClass);```

Than `myClass.pwm7Min = 0.5`

Comment: QML seems to be difficult. I stick to C++. No when I apply `Q_PROPERTY`, I still got my error message `QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method `

Comment: Because are you calling sometghing like setPwm7Min(x). You should show your QML because it's there your issie, but that is another question you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can only invoke methods known by the Qt meta object system with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, i.e. `slot` functions and `Q_INVOKABLE` functions.

Easiest way to register your getters and setters to `moc` is to add a separate `public` scope with the keyword `slots` for them in your header file:

```
public slots:
    void setInputCapture0Max(float inputCapture0Max);
```

Comment: OP said he's already using a property, so there's already a setter, but it's not the way it should be called from QML. He is aware he sould expose method to QML tha'ts why he would use Q_INVOKABLE, but it's not the way it solves his issue.

Comment: @Moia OP is not saying they have problems with the property from QML side, instead that they can't call the setter from C++ with QMetaObject::invokeMethod. That can be solved by making sure the setter is also a slot function.